# How can I list table columns (returned through an SQL query) as items in a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqldatareader, checkedlistbox

If I have the following table:

```
 canAssign 
------------
     1
```

Is there a way to add the column header text (e.g., `canAssign`, etc.) to the `CheckedListBox` as the labels that a user can check?

All answers I've found list the *value* as the labels, like this:

```
☐ 1
```

Instead of this:

```
☐ canAssign
```

For Example Only, If I'm using the following to list whatever value is in the canAssign column, how could I change this to list the 'canAssign' column header text?

```cs
string myString = "SELECT canAssign FROM Permissions";
using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(globalConnectionString)) 
{
    try {
        myConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand(myString, myConn)) 
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader = myComm.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read()) {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(myReader["canAssign"]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to include the code you're using right now, even though it's not working as you expect. That will make it easier to provide instruction by identifying where your examples are leading you astray. In particular, this is likely going to depend on _how_ you're retrieving your data from SQL, and _may_ require first mapping that data to some intermediary data model (like a `DataTable`, an array of enums, or a POCO with a `bool` for each column name).

Comment: your example gets CanAssign but not Admin, Active or CanDownload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the SQL query in your code snippet is to get the permissions of a specific user and display them in a CheckedListBox using the same fields names from the database.

If that sounds right, read the entry, loop to get the fields names and values through the [SqlDataReader.GetName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and [SqlDataReader.GetBoolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getboolean?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) methods respectively.

```cs
//For example...
var myString = "SELECT * FROM Permissions WHERE UserId = ....";

try
{
    using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(globalConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand(myString, myConn))
    {
        myConn.Open();

        using (var myReader = myComm.ExecuteReader())
            if (myReader.Read())
                for (var i = 0; i < myReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(myReader.GetName(i), myReader.GetBoolean(i));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think you'd like to have custom objects in [CheckedListBox.Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items?view=netcore-3.1) collection and use [CheckedListBox.DisplayMember property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.displaymember?view=netcore-3.1#:~:text=By%20default%20the%20CheckedListBox%20displays,by%20specifying%20the%20DisplayMember%20property.) with [CheckedListBox.ValueMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.valuemember?view=netcore-3.1)

**DisplayMember**

> Gets or sets a string that specifies a property of the objects
>   contained in the list box whose contents you want to display.

**ValueMember**

> Gets or sets a string that specifies the property of the data source
>   from which to draw the value.

**Example**

```cs
public class ListBoxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

checkedListBox.DisplayMember = "Text";
checkedListBox.ValueMember = "Value";

...create connection and create command logic...
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Permissions";
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read()) {

  // of course it would be better to cache that and go straight by indexes
  for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
     var columnName = reader.GetName(i);
     // some logic to humanize values like 'canDownload' to 'Can Download'
     var label = getLabelFor(columnName);
     var value = reader.GetBoolean(i);
     checkedListBox.Items.Insert(0, new ListBoxItem(label , value));
  }
}
```

Comment: A note on why the OP cannot find neither the DisplayMember nor the ValueMember properties wouldn't hurt. You should probably mention that `SelectedItem` needs to be cast and something about the *destiny* of `SelectedValue`.