# How can I update only columns associated with a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, checkedlistbox

I'm wondering how to update table columns if they are associated with a CheckedListBox but not otherwise.

For example take the following `Permissions` table:

```
Name |   Email     | Admin  | Subscribed | Newsletter
-----------------------------------------------------
John | j@email.com |   1    |     0      |      1
```

The last three columns need to be updated based on which values are checked in a CheckedListBox. I understand that I would normally do something like the following for each specified column:

```cs
string myQuery = "UPDATE Permissions SET Admin = @admin, Subscribed = @subscribed, Newsletter = @newsletter WHERE Name = 'John'";
using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString)) 
{
    try {
        myConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand(myQuery, myConn)) 
        {
            myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", int.Parse(admin.Text));
            myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subscribed", int.Parse(subscription.Text));
            myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsletter", int.Parse(newsletter.Text));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However this will not work with a `CheckedListBox`. How can I loop through a `CheckedListBox` and update ONLY the last three columns of the `Permissions` table?

Comment: _However this will not work with a CheckedListBox_ - why not?

Comment: Consider that a DataGridView is pretty much ideal for this sort of thing...and can result in trivial code to update the DB

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update the values of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62225384/10216583) entry where its fields names are the items of the CheckedListBox control.

You could create the `UPDATE` statement and execute it as follows:

```cs
var sql = string.Concat("UPDATE Permissions SET ",
    string.Join(", ", checkedListBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
    .Select((x, i) =>
    $"{x} = {Convert.ToInt32(checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))}")),
    @" WHERE Name = @name");

try
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "John");
        //Using the Add(..) method instead is highly recommended...
        //Select the correct SqlDbType and length for this field in the DB.
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "John";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch ( Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Another way, create an array of [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) type and use it to form the `UPDATE` statement, then add it to the [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) property of the [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) object:

```cs
var param = checkedListBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
    .Select((x, i) => new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = $"@{x}",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit,
        Value = Convert.ToInt32(checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)),
    }).Append(new SqlParameter("@name", "John")).ToArray();

var sql = string.Concat("UPDATE Permissions SET ",
    string.Join(", ",
    param.Take(param.Count() -1)
    .Select(x => $"{x.ParameterName.Substring(1)} = {x.ParameterName}")),
    $@" WHERE Name = {param.Last().ParameterName}");

try
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(someConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch ( Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Also, consider using the Ids of the entries in the `WHERE` clause when you update (or delete) instead of the string fields. Imagine what will happen when you execute the `UPDATE` command and you have more than one entry in the database with the same value in the `Name` field ("John").